# How to conditionally render a well panel in R Shiny?

Tags: css, r, shiny, formatting

Is it possible to conditionally render a `wellPanel()` (or equivalent) in R?

In the below code, clicking "Show!" correctly renders two objects jointly. I'd like them surrounded by a `wellPanel()` (or eqivalent shading) when they appear and have the `wellPanel()` disappear when clicking "Hide!". When first invoking the App, the default state is the two objects are hidden and the `wellPanel()` should also remain hidden.

Is there some CSS wizardry available for doing this sort of thing? Or other trick?

For many reasons I need to keep the general structure of this using shinyjs, the `toggleView()` function, etc.

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

toggleView <- function(input, output_name){
  observeEvent(input$show, {show(output_name)})
  observeEvent(input$hide, {hide(output_name)})
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(), 
  br(),
  actionButton("hide","Hide!"),
  actionButton("show","Show!"),
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(2,h5(hidden(textOutput("text")))),   
    column(6,hidden(tableOutput("table")))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- renderTable(iris[1:5,1:3])
  output$text <- renderText("Test show/hide in JS")
  toggleView(input, "table")
  toggleView(input, "text")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Maybe `?shiny::conditionalPanel()` can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify an id for the fluid row (or any parent element):

```
## UI part
## ... 
    fluidRow(id = "my_well",
## ...
```

and use this id to add/remove CSS classes with shinyjs:

```
## server part
## ...
  observeEvent(input$show, addClass("my_well", "well"), ignoreInit = TRUE)
  observeEvent(input$hide, removeClass("my_well", "well"), ignoreInit = TRUE)
## ...
```

Comment: Very simple solution and placing both elements into the same well panel is what I was after. I didn't know you could assign id's to parent elements like this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can give a HTML id to the wellpanels. The **shinyjs** functions `show` and `hide` are not restricted to output elements.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

toggleView <- function(input, id){
  observeEvent(input$show, {show(id)})
  observeEvent(input$hide, {hide(id)})
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(), 
  br(),
  actionButton("hide", "Hide!"),
  actionButton("show", "Show!"),
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      2,
      hidden(
        wellPanel(
          id = "panel_text",
          h5(textOutput("text"))   
        )
      )
    ),   
    column(
      6,
      hidden(
        wellPanel(
          id = "panel_table",
          tableOutput("table")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- renderTable(iris[1:5,1:3])
  output$text <- renderText("Test show/hide in JS")
  toggleView(input, "panel_table")
  toggleView(input, "panel_text")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```